# IntelliJ IDEA: the first compilation takes a lot of time

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to develop my Java application. I'm frustrated with the fact that the first compilation of a project (or a complete rebuild) takes very long, about 15 min (and is very CPU-intensive). The project is composed from a couple of hundreds of Java classes, but compiling it with Eclipse just need 1-2 minutes.

Are there any compilation options that I can set in order to speed up this step?

UPDATE

My configuration: SSD, 64GB RAM, Xeon E5-1660, Win 7 Ultimate

Compilation time (Rebuild):

- Eclipse: 30s
- IntelliJ IDEA with Eclipse compiler 45s
- IntelliJ IDEA with javac compiler: more than 10 minutes (!)

Number of java classes ~5000

Comment: Close all other projects?

Comment: A couple hundreds should compile in ~10 seconds on a modern computer, what is your configuration?

Comment: Is a virus scanner perhaps scanning all JARs in that project?

Comment: If it is noticeably slower, then report it as an issue.

Comment: Update: something definitely broken. They can fix it, if you report it...

Comment: Any progress so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from IntelliJ Support:

> Try 13.0.2 from
>   http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP .
>
> Disable the option to clean output directories on rebuild in the
>   compiler settings.

Answer (score 9):

Change the following setting (Build process heap size) to some large value

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Eclipse compiler from IntelliJ IDEA.

Enable the Eclipse compiler from Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler: "Use  compiler:" (change from Javac to Eclipse).

**update:** Here's my compilation times for a full rebuild, using IntelliJ IDEA 13 on a fairly large project:

```
Using javac 1.7.0_45 to compile java sources
Compilation completed successfully with 60 warnings in 27 sec

Using eclipse compiler to compile java sources
Compilation completed successfully with 652 warnings in 26 sec
```

So there seems to be something strange with your setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can also increase the heap size in the file `Intellij IDEA\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`. For example try these (assuming you have a lot of RAM):

```
-Xmx6g
-Xms6g
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-ea
-server
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Having done this, you need to start `idea` with `idea64.exe` because the default `32bit` version will not be able to use the big ram.

Answer (score 1):

1. We put our projects on a SSD drive and this speed up the IDEA
   rebuild significantly (about half the time).
2. I don't think you are comparing the same thing IDEA <-> eclipse somehow eclipse must have done some work already in the background or has a cache somewhere but I don't know eclipse well.